# Selección resultado SQL a excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

Buen día.

Tengo un resultado de una consulta **SQL Server** (select), el cual al seleccionar todo los registros con encabezados y pegarlos en **Excel** la información no queda organizada, es decir y según lo que observo: en **algunas** columnas toma espacios como salto nuevo fila/línea. Esto sucede con *SQL Server 2012*, pero al realizar el mismo proceso con *SQL Server 2008*, los mismos registros (mismo resultado), los copia y pega al *Excel* sin alterar el formato.

¿Por qué sucede esto?

¿Es algo de configuración del motor 2012?

> **Nota:** Me es necesario hacerlo con SQL 2012

Y lo he intentado con la opción de: *guardar como> txt,csv;* y separados por tabulación y el formato se altera en Excel de igual forma.

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: La salida de que te dá el motor siempre es la misma, lo que puede variar son las opciones a nivel cliente, deberías revisar esta configuración: Tools -> Options -> Query Results. Y lo otro que puedes revisar también son las configuraciones regionales de tu equipo

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿puedes copiar y pegar en un txt un ejemplo para los dos casos y agregarlo a tu pregunta? eso ayudaría bastante.

Comment: lo más probable es que el dato dentro de una columna no sea un espacio, sino algún caracter especial como salto de línea o similar. Trata de configurar las celdas en excel como texto y pegar

Comment: y al importar en Excel, fijate que tome las comillas como agrupador de campo